# How to iterate over values when std::vector::data is given

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function that returns in the following format:

```
 const value_type* data() const { return data_.data(); }
```

At the place from the call is placed. I am trying to iterate over the values. But unable to figure as how to get an iterator when pointer to the first element in the array used internally by the vector is given.

Calling side:

```
for (auto y:X.data()) std::cout << y << " " <<std::endl;
```

But getting an

```
error: invalid range expression of type 'const int *'; no viable 'begin' function available
```

Comment: You can't, because you don't know how many elements to iterate over.

Comment: Makes sense, only if I knew how many variables are there, then only I can build an iterator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the elements if you provide the `X::begin()` and `X::end()` functions.

Here is an example. I've commented out the proposed code snippets and replaced them with workable alternatives:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using value_type = int;

class X {
public:
    using my_iterator = const std::vector<value_type>::iterator;

    //const value_type* data() const { return data_.data(); }
    my_iterator begin() { return data_.begin(); }
    my_iterator end() { return data_.end(); }

private:
    std::vector<value_type> data_{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

};


int main()
{
    X x{};

    //for (auto y:X.data()) std::cout << y << " " <<std::endl;
    for (auto y:x) std::cout << y << " " <<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```